# Spotfire, Calculated Columns to show Percentages

Tags: percentage, calculated-columns, spotfire

I hope you are well and that you can be of assistance. I have a table and I need calculated columns to show what percentage of 'No' 'Yes' and 'Empty' I have. I have attached a picture below. 
[image]

Any help with the syntax would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

error screenshot posted by Philip Connell:

[image]

Comment: You want this in the cross table?

Comment: @scsimon: Yes please so in the example pic above we have a column 'No' 90 for Austria what i need is a column after that that has a heading No percentage and has 24.7% then after the 'Yes' column a percentage column that states 14.4% and for Empty 60.8%

Comment: @ scsimon: I have added a pic of what i am trying to achieve but its in Excel but it should give a good visual of what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is below

```
Count([CUSTOMER_ID]) as [No. Of Customers], Count([CUSTOMER_ID]) THEN [Value] / Sum([Value]) OVER (All([Axis.Columns])) as [Percentage ]
```

Thank you all for the support

Answer (score 2):

@Philip Connell - I have created a calculated column 'consent%' with the below expression and change the format of this column to percentage from column properties.

```
[number] / [Total amount]
```

Used this calculated column in a cross table. Screenshots below.
Please let me know if this is the solution you are looking for. 
[image]

**Refined solution:**

I have created some sample data for the sake of explanation.

[image]

Added pivot transformation (count of customer ID) while loading sample data into Spotfire.

[image]

Created two calculated columns.

Total amount:

> Sum([count  of Customer_ID]) over ([Country])

consent%:

> [count  of Customer_ID] / [Total amount]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. the second Screen shot is exactly what I am looking for. But How did you do it? Again thank you for the help is `[number] / [Total amount]` enough??

Comment: @Philip Connell - Yes, that expression should be enough for this data. If this solution helped, could you please accept my answer?

Comment: Happy to accept the answer but `[number] / [Total amount]`is not working. I changed `Total Amount` To `Total Country Amount`but  `Number`remains red. I have attached a pic for better understanding. Thak you again for the help.

Comment: number column is not present in your data. I used it as a dummy column for the sake of explanation. As per your screenshot, I think your data shows 'count of customer IDs'

Comment: could you please post some sample dummy data of your main table based on which you are creating this cross table? This would help me in refining my solution.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I am back in work now and happy to continue. I have put a sample table in the post above. My `Total Amount`is `Total Country Amount` and i got it by `Count([CUSTOMER_ID]) OVER ([Country])` now to get the percentage i think the syntax must be something like `count(if(consent)) = 'No' then /  Total Country Amount` . This would give in my table above 90/365 which is 24.7%. do we have to get the number of 'No' and Yes and Empties to complete the formula?